# neo4j1.4 ha "Graph database not assigned and no cause of shutdown, maybe not started yet or in the middle of master/slave swap?"

Tags: neo4j, high-availability, apache-zookeeper

**zookeeper 3.3.2 on solaris10 x64**

- at solaris 10 x64 config:

zookeeper 3.3.2 install /export/zookeeper-3.3.2
3 zookeeper dir

```
/export/zookeeper1
/export/zookeeper2
/export/zookeeper3
```

startup.sh

```
nohup /jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java -cp zookeeper-3.3.2.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:conf org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain ../zookeeper1/conf/zoo.cfg > nohup1.txt &

nohup /jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java -cp zookeeper-3.3.2.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:conf org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain ../zookeeper2/conf/zoo.cfg > nohup2.txt &

nohup /jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java -cp zookeeper-3.3.2.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:conf org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain ../zookeeper3/conf/zoo.cfg > nohup3.txt &
```

zookeeper1
zoo.cfg

```
tickTime = 2000
initLimit = 10
syncLimit = 5
dataDir = /export/zookeeper1/data
dataLogDir = /export/zookeeper1/log
clientPort = 2181
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

zookeeper2
zoo.cfg

```
tickTime = 2000
initLimit = 10
syncLimit = 5
dataDir = /export/zookeeper2/data
dataLogDir = /export/zookeeper2/log
clientPort = 2182
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

zookeeper3
zoo.cfg

```
tickTime = 2000
initLimit = 10
syncLimit = 5
dataDir = /export/zookeeper3/data
dataLogDir = /export/zookeeper3/log
clientPort = 2183
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

neo4j 1.4 install windows 7
neo4j code

```
String path = "var/graph.ha";
Map<String, String> config = HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.loadConfigurations("conf/neo4j.cfg");
```

conf/neo4j.cfg

```
allow_store_upgrade=true
ha.machine_id = 1
ha.cluster_name = neo4j.ha
ha.server = localhost:6001
ha.zoo_keeper_servers = zoohost:2181,zoohost:2182,zoohost:2183
ha.pull_interval = 600
ha.allow_init_cluster = true
enable_remote_shell = port=1331
```

**startup neo4j ha exception message:**

2011-11-02 12:46:44,316 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeper@373] - Initiating client connection, connectString= zoohost:2181, zoohost:2182, zoohost:2183 sessionTimeout=5000 watcher=org.neo4j.kernel.ha.zookeeper.ZooClient@16fa474
2011-11-02 12:46:44,674 - INFO  [main-SendThread():ClientCnxn$SendThread@1041] - Opening socket connection `enter code here`to server / zoohost:2183
java.lang.RuntimeException: Graph database not assigned and no cause of shutdown, maybe not started yet or in the middle of master/slave swap?
        at org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.localGraph(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:282)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.startUp(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:240)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:135)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that there might be problems caused by misconfiguration of /etc/hosts somehow. Could you look for exceptions in storeDir/messages.log? Also did you set the zk/myid files correctly?

Also use 1.4.2 instead of 1.4 since it's has major improvements in the HA area.

Answer (score 0):

question resolve. neo4j.cfg file ip replace host name.